# Is it possible to have SyncAdapter in a library?

Tags: android

I am developing a library that will be used by multiple applications.
The library needs to do network sync and I have created a [stub provider and account as described here](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).

The problem is, that android:authorities inside provider tag in manifest must be unique. I could have the library consumer define that in their manifest, but then in syncadapter.xml android:contentAuthority in sync-adapter tag that resides in my library would have a wrong value. Is there any way to change android:contentAuthority programatically?

Or, is SyncAdapter in this case not a correct pattern, when I want to do synchronization inside the library?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that [the placeholder system included in manifest merging with Android Studio/Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support) will handle placeholders in libraries, though I am not 100% certain.

Comment: I usually use the application's package name as a part of the authority (for content providers at least) so it can be used in 2 apps without interfering

Comment: @ConmmonsWare, this seemed promising. Unfortunately, the placeholders seem to only be replaced in manifest files. I also need to name the authority in syncadapter.xml metadata file. Gradle doesn't seem to touch that. I unzipped .apk and the placeholder was there in syncadapter.xml without replacement :(. Is it possible to have SyncAdapter without corresponding syncadapter.xml metadata file?

Comment: Is there still no accepted solution to this scenario?

Comment: Having the same issue. Any one found a proper solution?