# Does placeholder support only work with manifest files?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In search for the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994503/is-it-possible-to-have-syncadapter-in-a-library), I was referred to  [the placeholder system included in manifest merging with Android Studio/Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support).

That seems to work only for manifest files. Is there any way to use placeholders in metadata files in /res/xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Placeholders are only implemented for manifest merging. Trying to do them in XML files would be really complicated. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994503/is-it-possible-to-have-syncadapter-in-a-library and it was suggested to use placeholders. The reason I need placeholder in XML is that syncadapter's contentAuthority is defined in XML file. If there was another way to define it (code) I would be a happy camper. Thanks.